# how do you pass a list for an sql IN in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using postgres and I am trying to do a query along the lines of:

```
 Foo.where("(bar > ?) OR (baz IN ?)", bar_min, baz_array)
```

the bar_min seems fine, But no matter what I try, I can't seem to find a correct way to pass the baz_array into the query

Comment: Have you tried this `Foo.where("bar > ? OR baz IN (?)", bar_min, baz_array)`

Comment: thanks, that works. the brackets around the second "?" seems to be what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I hope this will help.

```
Foo.where("bar > ? OR baz IN (?)", bar_min, baz_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arel table

```
foo = Foo.arel_table
Foo.where(foo[:bar].gt(bar_min).or(foo[:baz].in(baz_array)))
```